# VAT always 0% even though settings seem to be correct

Tags: magento2, tax

I setup a new store and added my tax classes and everything. I opened the product, set the tax class and saved, reindexed, emptied caches but the VAT on the product page or list page is always 0%.

I also set the country of origin and set the prices to include tax on the frontend. PLease also take a look at the tax settings here: https://screenshots.firefox.com/0y6mBZZmGz6SFtYe/www.alltagsflucht.de

Any ideas what else might be missing?

**Magento 2.2.5 with sample data**

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your tax settings under Shops > Configuration > Tax? Especially the first 4 parts of the accordion.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I added a screenshot in my post.

Comment: Did you use Firegento_GermanSetup? I'd recommend installing it. It will setup all taxes at the start. Also, does it work on Luma Theme without 3rd party modules active?

Comment: Yeah, I used Firegento MageSetup and I have all the tax rules and stuff, but it still is not working :(.